# Finding objects by attributes of their last child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example, let's say I have two models: `Parent` and `Child`

**parent.rb**

```
has_many :children
```

**child.rb**

```
belongs_to :parent
```

I'd like to find all parents where either `parent.children.last.gender == "boy"` OR `parent.volunteer == "yes"`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to have "last child is a boy" or will "has a child who is a boy" work?
This will work a latter:

```
Parent.includes(:child).where("children.gender = 'boy' or parents.volunteer = 'yes'")
```

For last child is a boy:
Here is the equivalent of what you need in SQL, you can probably use `find_by_sql` to get it working or create something similar using rails syntax or Arel.

```
select p.* from parents p inner join 
(select parent_id, gender from children where id in (select max(id) from children group by parent_id)) c
on c.parent_id = p.id where p.volunteer = 'Yes' OR c.gender = 'Boy';
```

Depending on the size of your database this query might be pretty expensive to run, alternative solution could be to store last child gender on the parent record, and update it every time new child is added if it's a different gender from what parent has currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need "last child is a boy". Which is why I'm having such a struggle determining how to do this.

Comment: No problem, it's just an uglier query still possible.

Comment: Do you what that uglier query might be?

Comment: Thanks, @iouri. I ultimately decided to update the parent record with a `last_child_gender` attribute, as I agree that this query as often as necessary would be quite taxing.